# "Missing { inserted" error without any mathematical expression in a table

Tags: tables

I am trying to create a table in LaTeX, but I am encountering the error "Missing { inserted" when compiling my code. How can I resolve this issue?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{quantikz}
\begin{document}


\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\textbf{Gate} & \textbf{\# of Qubits} & \textbf{Matrix} & \textbf{Circuit Diagram}
& \textbf{Info} \\ \hline

X-Pauli & 1 &
$\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 
\end{bmatrix}$ &

\begin{quantikz}
\lstick{\ket{0}} & \gate{X} & \qw \rstick{\ket{1}} \
\end{quantikz}
& NOT gate \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

The error is coming from the line `& NOT gate \\ \hline`. I am not sure exactly where the problem is coming from since I do not intend to use a mathematical expression anyways. I have tried a few different things such as putting `NOT gate` in curly brackets or other similar things, but none have worked.

Please let me know if you spot any problems.

Comment: Welcome TeX.SE @josh I'm not sure, but I think there's some kind of interference with `quantikz` environment or another? Check if all braces are balanced and if there's enough `&` as columns.

Comment: That is what my hunch says too. I have looked at all the braces and they look balanced to me, but I know my eyes could still deceive me.

Comment: `quantikz` makes `&` globally active. Not really a good choice.

Comment: what would be a good choice then? what are the alternatives and what is the implication of "`quantikz` makes `&` globally active"?

Comment: Your eyes are good, I can confirm after checking too. As @egreg pointed out the problem is related to `quantikz` :( A workaroud would be a kind of externalisation (I though of a new command defined earlier, but saved box in the proposed answer is a very good too.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `quantikz` library makes `&` globally into an active character. This is not a good choice, in my opinion and Ti*k*Z generally doesn't do it even if it does (locally) for some libraries.

As a consequence, `quantikz` environments never work inside `tabular`.

Workaround: redefine the `quantikz` environment, which is actually just `tikzcd`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{quantikz}

\RenewDocumentEnvironment{quantikz}{O{}}{%
  \begin{tikzcd}[#1]}{\end{tikzcd}}

% fix the wrongdoing
\catcode`&=4

\begin{document}

  \begin{quantikz}
  \lstick{\ket{0}} & \gate{X} & \qw \rstick{\ket{1}}
  \end{quantikz}


\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\textbf{Gate} & \textbf{\# of Qubits} & \textbf{Matrix} & \textbf{Circuit Diagram}
& \textbf{Info} \\ \hline
X-Pauli & 1 &
$\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 
\end{bmatrix}$ &
  \begin{quantikz}
  \lstick{\ket{0}} & \gate{X} & \qw \rstick{\ket{1}}
  \end{quantikz}
& NOT gate \\ \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you nest `quantikz` in the argument to another command, use `ampersand replacement`, such as in

```
\begin{quantikz}[ampersand replacement=\&]
  \lstick{\ket{0}} \& \gate{X} \& \qw \rstick{\ket{1}}
\end{quantikz}
```

Comment: this is a good workaround. I was not familiar with `\newsavebox` command. I would like an approach that is more generalizable and more on the fly. Suppose I want to create more rows with more diagrams. Currently, I have to predefine a `\sbox` for each one of them. I prefer to be able to use `quantikz` inside the table. Something like 
`\begin{quantikz}[ampersand replacement=\&]
  \lstick{\ket{0}} \& \gate{X} \& \qw \rstick{\ket{1}}
  \end{quantikz}%` inside the table would have been great, but alas this gives the same error as before. Is there a more generalizable/flexible workaround?

Comment: Actually, this is documented, but it's "buried" in section X.  There's a footnote on page 1 of the documentation that says to "see X" if `&` is needed in math.  That could profitably be extended to say "in math or `quantikz` is used in a table".  Should be sent to author of the package as a suggestion.  This would be a good example to accompany the report.

Comment: @Josh I found a *much* simpler solution.

Comment: Works like a charm! Simple, flexible and generalizable!

Comment: I was still able to make it work without the line \catcode`&=4, do you know if it is necessary?

Comment: @Josh Other packages may rely on `&` having catcode 4.